# domain of the fractional laplacian operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $L$ be an operator on $C^2(\mathbb R)$, defined by
$$L \phi (x) = \int_{|y|<1} (\phi(x+y) - \phi(x) - \phi'(x) \ y)\ \nu(dy), \quad \forall x\in \mathbb R$$
for a measure $\nu(dy) = |y|^{-2} dy$. One can see that $L\phi$ is well defined for $\phi\in C^2$ since $|\phi(x+y) - \phi(x) - \phi'(x) \ y| \le K_x y^2$ in $B_1(x)$. Note that the definition of $L$ is explicitly dependent up to the first derivative of $\phi$.

[Q]. Is there a function $\phi \in C^1 \setminus C^2$, such that $L \phi $ is not well defined?

Comment: The region of integration should be $|y|<1$.

Comment: thanks. it's corrected now.